# error: cannot access zzbfm class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbfm not found (java location listener problem) app level build gradle

Tags: java, android, build.gradle, locationlistener, android-studio-3.1

I get this error message:

> error: cannot access zzbfm
>   class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbfm not found

Since i changed location listener parameters i'am encountering this error, i had to change cause it showed error previously saying 3rd party parameters.

Here is my app level build gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.chinmayi.androiduberclone"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    //add library
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.github.kmenager:material-animated-switch:1.2.2'
    implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
    implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

And here is the source code:

```
package com.example.chinmayi.androiduberclone;

    import android.Manifest;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationListener;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.SystemClock;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.animation.Interpolator;
    import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.firebase.geofire.GeoFire;
    import com.firebase.geofire.GeoLocation;
    import com.github.kmenager.materialanimatedswitch.MaterialAnimatedSwitch;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

    public class Welcome extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
            GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
            GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
            LocationListener

    {

        private GoogleMap mMap;

        private static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE =7000;
        private static final int PLAYY_SERVICE_ES_REQUEST = 7001;

        private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
        private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
        private Location mLastLocation;

        private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 5000;
        private static int FASTEST_INTERVAL =3000;
        private static int DISPLACEMENT = 10;

        DatabaseReference drivers;


        GeoFire geoFire;

        Marker mCurrent;

        MaterialAnimatedSwitch location_switch;

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

        FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
            // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
            mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

            location_switch = (MaterialAnimatedSwitch)findViewById(R.id.location_switch);
            location_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new MaterialAnimatedSwitch.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(boolean isOnline) {
                    if(isOnline)
                    {
                        startLocationUpdates();
                        displayLocation();
                        Snackbar.make(mapFragment.getView(),"You are online",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        stopLocationUpdates();
                        mCurrent.remove();
                        Snackbar.make(mapFragment.getView(),"You are offline",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
                }
            });
            //Geo Fire
            drivers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Drivers");
            geoFire = new GeoFire(drivers);

            setUpLocation();

        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            switch (requestCode)
            {
                case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                    if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    {
                        if(checkPlayServices())
                        {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                            createLocationRequest();
                            if(location_switch.isChecked())
                                displayLocation();
                        }
                    }
            }
        }

        private void setUpLocation() {
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED  )
            {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String []{
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                },MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
            else
            {
                if(checkPlayServices())
                {
                    buildGoogleApiClient();
                    createLocationRequest();
                    //fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
                    if(location_switch.isChecked())
                        displayLocation();
                }
            }
        }

        private void createLocationRequest() {
            mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
        }

        private void buildGoogleApiClient() {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

        private boolean checkPlayServices() {
            int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
            if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
                if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode))
                    GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, PLAYY_SERVICE_ES_REQUEST).show();
                 else
                    {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "This device is not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                    }
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        private void stopLocationUpdates() {
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED  )
            {
                return;
            }
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);
        }

        private void displayLocation() {
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED  )
            {
                return;
            }
            mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            if(mLastLocation!=null)
            {
                if(location_switch.isChecked())
                {
                    final double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
                    final double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

                    //Upgrade
                    geoFire.setLocation(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid(), new GeoLocation(latitude, longitude), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
                            if(mCurrent!=null)
                            {
                                mCurrent.remove();
                                mCurrent=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car))
                                                            .position(new LatLng(latitude,longitude))
                                                            .title("You"));

                                //move camera to this position
                                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude,longitude),15.0f));

                                //draw animation rotation marker
                                rotateMarker(mCurrent,-360,mMap);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("ERROR","Cannot get your location");
            }

        }

        private void rotateMarker(final Marker mCurrent, final float i, GoogleMap mMap) {
            final Handler handler=new Handler();
            final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            final float startRotation = mCurrent.getRotation();
            final long duration = 1500;

            final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
                    float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float)elapsed/duration);
                    float rot = t*i+(1-t)*startRotation;
                    mCurrent.setRotation(-rot > 180?rot/2:rot);
                    if(t<1.0)
                    {
                        handler.postDelayed(this,16);
                    }
                }
            });


        }

        private void startLocationUpdates() {
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED  )
            {
                return;
            }
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,mLocationRequest, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);
           // fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,mLocationRequest,(com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener)this);
        }


        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap = googleMap;


        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            mLastLocation = location;
            displayLocation();

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
            displayLocation();
            startLocationUpdates();

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: You really shouldnt drop so much code on us. Most likely, this is more of a setup problem anyway. The exception says that a class can not be found. So your project setup is probably broken. Have you tried resetting/rebuilding things?